# Two way hyperlink and raised hyperlink target causing build errors

Tags: memoir, endnotes, hyperlink

I have fused two methods to create two way hyperlinks for my endnotes (endnotes/pagenotes from memoir).

The methods used for [two way links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434958/how-can-i-configure-two-way-hypertarget-hyperlink-pairs) and a fix for [links that aim to low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low).

The result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\linkdest{endnote1-body}
Additional information on translations, as well as deviations\makeatletter\hyperlink{endnote1-appendix}\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{endnote1-body}{\pagenote{%
  \hypertarget{endnote1-appendix}{\hyperlink{endnote1-body}{Due to the balanced and inspiring selection of chants, as well as for the sake of compatability, WPN \textit{Buddhist Chanting} {2014} has served as the basis for this book. Over time, suggestions for the inclusion of additional chants, as well as occasional improvements of existing translations were incorporated. Such changes were meticulously marked down in the endnotes, so that someone familiar with the SBS recitation book can straight away find the relevant differences, which can be useful when visiting a branch monastery of the Ajahn Chah lineage, in order to know in which places to revert to the original version.}}}}}\makeatother\thickspace
from WPN \textit{Buddhist Chanting} (2014), have been annotated by Ven. Ariyadhammika in the endnotes.

\end{document}
```

I end up with a duplicate destination error

```
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'endnote1-body'
```

Before fixing this, would it be possible to enable a two way hyperlink for endnotes through memoir without having to manual set a two way hyperlink? The main reason for the raised link is because the two way link was aiming too low.

If not, how would I structure this combination to solve the error?

Let me know what other information would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: compare your question with the two questions you linked too and then ask yourself what your question could be missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer are you referring to the preamble?

Comment: @paladhammika I believe Ulrike is referring to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306). When asking questions, code fragments are undesirable as they cannot be reproduced - what packages are you loading, in what order, what commands have you created etc. Check that link and then edit your question to include a MWE please, perhaps someone can help afterwards. Start from `\documentclass{}`, include **relevant** packages and commands and include `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` please.

Comment: well you are setting the same anchor/destination/target twice: once with `\linkdest{endnote1-body}` and once with `\hypertarget{endnote1-body}`, so naturally pdftex will complain.

Comment: My thanks @UlrikeFischer -- this was too simple. I started with the two-way link and only later added the raised link. So wasn't sure if the hypertarget was needed.